# Can you make it so that MathJax appears on mobile on the list of all open questions instead of raw LaTeX?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Is there a way to make it so that equations and mathematical type looks formatted on mobile (iOS) devices on the main page (where the questions are)? Thanks!

Comment: It may help if you add a screenshot example to your post.